# Setting system-wide locale on Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, locale

For some reason, my Sierra install doesn't have the locale set properly. I have exported the locale settings properly for Terminal and shell purposes, but if I execute the `locale` command from outside a shell, I get this:

```
​LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

How do I set the system-wide, non-shell locale?

Answer (score 0):

By "outside a shell" you mean in an app run from the GUI (Finder, Dock, Launchpad, etc.)? Also, you'll need to specify what you need the locale to affect, what API you want to use that's locale-dependent.

If you're using the C library, you'll need to construct the appropriate locale string and pass that to `setlocale()`, rather than using `""`. (Or, you could use `setenv()` to set the relevant environment variables before calling `setlocale(..., "")`, but that seems roundabout.)

So, from where do you get the information to construct that locale string? You can use [`NSLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale) if using Objective-C. You can also use that from Swift, but the Swift-ier API is [`Locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale). If you're using C or some other language with a C binding, you would use [`CFLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cflocale?language=objc).

**However**, there's a significant caveat. The C library on macOS supports many fewer locales than those high-level APIs. If you construct a locale string based on the high-level APIs, pass that to the C library, and the C library doesn't support it, you still end up in the "C" locale. You could potentially do better by using only some of the locale information (e.g. leave out the country code).

For a (somewhat convoluted) example of this approach, you can look at the source code of Wine, but be aware that it's LGPLv2. Look at the `__APPLE__`-specific code in [this file](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/3ebd2f0be30611e6cf00468c2980c5092f91b5b5/dlls/kernel32/locale.c#L958).

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a PYTHON app that is being run from the GUI. I'm using Platypus to assemble the python script into an app. However, it errors out because my script also uses the click library (for command line argument handling) and click requires the locales to be set.

Comment: You can use [PyObjC](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/) to access either the Objective-C or C APIs I mentioned (`from Foundation import *` or `from CoreFoundation import *`). PyObjC ships with macOS (although it's an old version).